# How can I call method only one time before test is started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to call setup method before test of rails is started.
[setup or teardown method of ActiveSupport](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/SetupAndTeardown.html) could not be used.
Because, this method is called each test.
This method should be called only one time.

How can I Implement?

My environment is following
Rails 4.0.13
DB is postgres
Rspec is not used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

- add it to `config/environments/test.rb`
- add it in an initializer in `config/initializers` and only run it in the test environment `my_code.run if Rails.env.test?`
- add it to `test/test_helper.rb`

I'd be inclined to add it to the top of `test_helper.rb` if it's trivial and maybe create an initializer if not.

Comment: Thanks!! I could call method only one time.